# Can I use Aircrack-ng with my RTL8723BE?

Tags: aircrack-ng

I have a HP laptop, with the RTL8723BE wireless adapter. I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and want to use Aircrack-ng. Is this adapter compatible with Aircrack? (Indeed, does this matter or is it only the drivers which make the difference?) I want to monitor and inject packages. I have not installed any driver yet.

On the Aircrack-ng [installing drivers](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=install_drivers) page, RTL8723BE is not mentioned as a supported adapter. Is there a way to install the appropriate drivers which support monitor mode and injection with RTL8723BE?

Also, this adapter supports 802.11 b/g/n and has an Intel chipset (I don’t know exactly which).

Answer (score 1):

I am using Lenovo's G50-70 with wireless chipset of RTL8723BE. I believe that this model doesn't support packet injection. I am using external USB wireless adapter for practicing with aircrack-ng.

Answer (score 1):

If it is not listed in aircrack-ng list then possibly it is not supported. Try something else.